# How to know if a list is filled with a same number in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, fill

I manipulating big list in my program, so what's the fastest way to know if a list is filled with a same number ? And I'm not able to use module.

As example :

```
>>> isFilled([1,1,1,1,1])
True
>>> isFilled([5,5,5,5])
True
>>> isFilled([1,6,5,1,1])
False
```

I have done this, but it's create a new list and that's a problem as I manipulating big list :

```
def isFilled(lst):
    return [lst[0]]*len(lst) in lst
```

Comment: Is an empty list considered filled?

Comment: An empty list as input should be considered by answers, as most of them currently break on an empty list - `IndexError` on `lst[0]`.

Comment: No, I don't work with empty list.

Comment: *I don't work with empty list* - famous last words :)

Comment: I think you should still consider the possibility of an empty list anyway. Writing a program that crashes on an input that you think will never occur is very bad practice.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: what about writing a function that throws an exception on encountering an incorrect input (which is all that's happening here)? Is that very bad practice? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop No (at least not in Python). But from the OP's response, it didn't sound like he would put a `try` `except` around a call of this function. I was trying to say that "This input never occurs so I don't need to worry about it" is a bad excuse for not covering the case when that input occurs.

Comment: Sure, we need to worry about that special case, however in my program, this case does not occur at all. But I'm aware of this kind of exception, trust me. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here: `all(x==lst[0] for x in lst)`. `(x==lst[0] for x in lst)` is a [generator comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` if all the elements of an iterator (a generator comprehension is an iterator) return `True` when passed to [`bool()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool), which converts a value into a boolean value (`True` or `False`). Note that it evaluates as `False` immediately after a different element is spotted.

Comment: Your variables names are all wrong. It should be `x==l[0] for x in l`

Comment: This is good as it is lazy - returns the very moment the condition is not met.

Answer (score 2):

Either the list is empty (in that case all elements are the same) or we should compare all elements to the first until one is different. all() does that.

```
def isFilled(lst):
    if not lst:  # Empty
        return True
    return all(element == lst[0] for element in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner

```
def isFilled(myList):
    return len(set(myList)) == 1
```

Or

```
def isFilled(myList):
    first = myList[0]
    return not any(first != item for item in myList)
```

Comment: But if myList is large and all its elements unique, the created set will be large too.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Check that now. I have come up with an alternative :)

Comment: You could do `==` and remove the `not` in the second answer, which might make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @sweeneyrod That will make the logic wrong. OP wants to make sure all of them are the same not any of them are the same.

Comment: @thefourtheye Oh, I didn't read it properly and presumed that it was `all`. Well, if you changed it to that, my point still stands!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.count`:

```
>>> def isFilled(lis):
    return bool(lis) and lis.count(lis[0]) == len(lis)
... 
>>> isFilled([1,1,1,1,1])
True
>>> isFilled([1,6,5,1,1])
False
>>> isFilled([])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be overthinking this. What about a simple `for` loop:

```
def isFilled(lst):
    try:
        n = lst[0]
    except IndexError:
        return True        # I'm assuming that an empty list is considered filled
    for i in lst:
        if i != n:
            return False
    return True
```

Alternatively, for brevity, readability *and* efficiency I think `not lst or all(i == lst[0] for i in lst)` is best. The `not lst` ensures that an empty list is considered filled, and that not `IndexError` is raised if the list is empty. If an empty list isn't considered filled, then you want `bool(lst) and all(i == lst[0] for i in lst)`.

Both of these have O(n) time complexity. The `for` loop has O(1) space complexity, and the `all` has O(1) (if `all` is implemented well).

Answer (score 1):

Use `len`:

```
len(set(myList)) <= 1
```

Or the `all` function and a bit of LC:

```
all(v != l[i-1] for i,v in enumerate(l) if i)
```

Answer (score 1):

And the more generic version that'll work on all iterables (not just lists):

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    fst = next(i, object())
    return all(el == fst for el in i)
```

If an empty iterable should not be considered all the same, then:

```
i = iter(a)
empty = object()
fst = next(i, empty)
return fst is not empty and all(el == fst for el in i)
```